# Get list of result files converted via Wand

Tags: python, imagemagick, magickwand, wand

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is open source software suite for displaying, converting, and editing raster image files. [Wand](http://docs.wand-py.org) is a [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes)-based ImageMagick binding for Python.

**How do i get the list of image files, which i got as a result of using Wand?**

For example there is a 2-page PDF file `file.pdf` and i converted it to 2 JPEG files `file-0.jpg` and `file-1.jpg`. How do i get the list `['file-0.jpg', 'file-1.jpg']`?

Currently i simply use `glob`:

```
with Image(filename='file.pdf') as original:
    with original.clone() as converted:
        converted.format = 'jpeg'
        converted.save(filename='file.jpg')
images = glob('*.jpg')
```

But maybe there is a more idiomatic way through Wand library itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Image.sequence](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.sequence). Each sequence item has [index](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/wand/sequence.html#wand.sequence.Sequence).

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='file.pdf') as img:
    img.save(filename='file.jpg')
    if len(img.sequence) > 1:
        images = ['file-{0.index}.jpg'.format(x) for x in img.sequence]
    else:
        images = ['file.jpg']
```